# Blocking vs. Non Blocking network IO in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, parallel-processing, polling

I have some python code that was written by a developer before me. It sends UDP messages to nodes in a P2P network. I am writing a parallel version of that code. This code sends multiple parallel messages to the P2P network. Unfortunately, the code is consuming too much CPU. I am assuming it is because of all the network I/O polling. Will it be a good idea if I used asynchronous I/O (twisted framework)?

Comment: consider using gevent instead of twisted - you may be able to monkey patch your socket code to be asynchronous without changing your application. YMMV

Comment: There's any number of potential reasons that your program uses too much CPU.  Using Twisted is a good idea, but you haven't provided enough information for anyone to know if it will address the problem you've raised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yes.](http://twistedmatrix.com/)

Comment: ^^ Love it. My Answer would have been yellow